# How momentjs businessDiff() works?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello guys I am working on a project which needs to calculate the difference between two dates and result the total number of business days so I am using businessDiff function of momentjs.

My issue comes when its about one day only where starting is set at 00:00:00 and ending at 23:59:00 in theory this is one business day but the result it return as 0 days.

Does anyone have an idea how this is calculated?

here is how I use this

```
var startingTime = moment(periodEnd).toDate(); // 2019-11-13T00:00:00.000Z
startingTime.setHours(0);
startingTime.setMinutes(0);
startingTime.setSeconds(0);
startingTime.setMilliseconds(0);

var endingTime = moment(periodStart).toDate(); // 2019-11-13T23:59:00.000Z
endingTime.setHours(23);
endingTime.setMinutes(59);
endingTime.setSeconds(00);
endingTime.setMilliseconds(0);

const numberOfWorkingDays = moment(startingTime).businessDiff(
  moment(endingTime)
);

console.log(numberOfWorkingDays); // 0
```

Comment: It's one minute less than a day

Comment: @Pointy I know but I was expected to get something like 0.9 and round it to 1

Comment: did you find an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/kalmecak/moment-business-days/blob/af548cba8a384a11d67d2bc4575bb3bbf3e975ce/index.js) of the `businessDiff` function, it will return 0 in the case you described.

```js
moment.fn.businessDiff = function (param, relative) {
  var d1 = this.clone();
  var d2 = param.clone();
  var positive = d1 >= d2;
  var start = d1 < d2 ? d1 : d2;
  var end = d2 > d1 ? d2 : d1;

  var daysBetween = 0;

  // this will return true since it's the same day, and will in fact return 0
  if (start.format('DD/MM/YYYY') === end.format('DD/MM/YYYY')) {
    return daysBetween;
  }

  while (start < end) {
    if (start.isBusinessDay()) {
      daysBetween++;
    }
    start.add(1, 'd');
  }

  if (relative) {
    return positive ? daysBetween : -daysBetween;
  }

  return daysBetween;
};
```

Comment: So, they calculate the date only not the time as well. Now make sense