# Identify weekend dates within range of date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, momentjs

I am trying to compute number of days between a range of dates input by the user using date picker using the following script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker();
            $('#datepicker2').datepicker();
            $('#datepicker3').datepicker();
            $('#datepicker4').datepicker();
            
            $(function() {
                let $fromDate = $('#fromdate'),
                    $toDate = $('#todate'),
                    $numberDays = $('#leavedays'),
                    $sfromDate=$('#sfromdate'),
                    $stoDate=$('#stodate'),
                    $snumberDays=$('#sleavedays');
                    

                $fromDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
                    $toDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());
                    $numberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($toDate.val(), $(this).val())+1);
                });

                $toDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
                    $fromDate.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).val());
                    $numberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($(this).val(), $fromDate.val())+1);
                });

                $sfromDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
                    $stoDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());
                    $snumberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($stoDate.val(), $(this).val())+1);
                });

                $stoDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
                    $sfromDate.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).val());

                    $snumberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($(this).val(), $sfromDate.val())+1);
                });

                function calculateDateDiff(endDate, startDate) {
                        

                    if (endDate && startDate) {
                        let e = moment(endDate),
                            s = moment(startDate);

                        return e.diff(s, "days");
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            });
         });
```

The script is able to return the correct difference between from date and to date, but I want to exclude weekend while computing the difference. Please help how to proceed for the same

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to adjust the input arguments to be the first/last day of the week, then divide by 7 to determine how many weekends in between those dates that you need to remove:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k3uxeo12/3/

```
function calculateDateDiff(endDate, startDate) {

    if (endDate && startDate) {
        let e = moment(endDate),
            s = moment(startDate);

        let days = e.diff(s, "days") + 1; // diff only counts the boundary, so add 1
        
        // .isoWeekday() returns 1-7 where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday
        // Adjust the end to the Friday before, if it is a weekend
        if (e.isoWeekday() > 5)
            days -= e.isoWeekday() % 5; // will be 1 for Saturday, 2 for Sunday
        
        // adjust the start to the next Monday, if it is a weekend
        if (s.isoWeekday() > 5)
            days -= (3 - (s.isoWeekday() % 5)); // will be 2 for Saturday, 1 for Sunday

        if (days > 5) {
            // remove the weekends from each full week
            let weeks = (days - (days % 7)) / 7;
            days -= (weeks * 2);
        }
        
        return days;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Having a quick search you can find other very similar posts:

- [How momentjs businessDiff() works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58839564/1690217)

  - [GitHub: kalmecak/moment-business-days/index.js](https://github.com/kalmecak/moment-business-days/blob/af548cba8a384a11d67d2bc4575bb3bbf3e975ce/index.js)
- [npm: moment-business-days](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days)

Answer (score 0):

Not DatePicker related but in terms of time, I only get the value of the date and send it to the server. This is what I did using PHP,

```
function getDatesFromRange($start, $end, $format = 'Ymd') {
$array = array();
$day = 'D';
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$realEnd = new DateTime($end);
$realEnd->add($interval);

$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($start), $interval, $realEnd);

foreach($period as $date) { 
    $day_name = $date->format($day);
    $date = $date->format($format);

    $array[] = array(
        'date' => $date,
        'day' => $day_name,
        'duration' => $day_name == 'Sun' ? "It's weekend!" : "Not a weekend.",
    );
}
return $array;} echo "<pre>"; print_r(getDatesFromRange('20221125', '20221224')); echo "</pre>";
```

I found the method somewhere and modified it a little bit. It will output the following:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20221125
        [day] => Fri
        [duration] => Not a weekend.
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20221126
        [day] => Sat
        [duration] => Not a weekend.
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20221127
        [day] => Sun
        [duration] => It's weekend!
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20221128
        [day] => Mon
        [duration] => Not a weekend.
    )
```

...and so on. I think it's easier to apply only restrictions to the frontend but the real logic was on the backend... sorry for my english